# Code from macro execution

Tags: sas, sas-macro

To create a complex analysis, I have a program that will %include some different other programs, each one with a specific purpose (mainly one for each analysis, one for macros, one for formats and so on..). All the analysis run smoothly with one click on the final program.

Basically what I want now is to implement a system that will be able to rewrite all the code in one document: exploding the macros with the correct code, exploding the %do loops with the correct datastep code, deleting the %let statements but resolving the macro variables, and so on (example at the bottom of the post).

The only idea I had was to save the log, with the MPRINT option to write everything, delete the notes after the datastep executions and other things not datastep related. But this method is really dirty, therefore I would kindly ask if you have better ideas on how to proceed.

This is an example of 2 nested programs:

```
main.sas

-----------------------------------------------------

/* My MAIN PROGRAM */

%let PGM=MAIN;
%put This is my &pgm. program;

%let LIB=MYLIB;

%include &LIB.(FIRST.sas);

-----------------------------------------------------

first.sas

-----------------------------------------------------

%let ind=2;

%macro ABC;
%do rk=1 %to &ind.;

data A&rk.;
MYVAR=&rk.; output;
run;

%end;
%mend; %ABC;

-----------------------------------------------------
```

The document that I would get is something like:

```
/* My MAIN PROGRAM */

%put This is my MAIN program;

data A1;
MYVAR=1; output;
run;

data A2;
MYVAR=2; output;
run;
```

Any suggestion? Did you ever find out this? How you solved it? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See Example 2 here:

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/69726/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1dhqw0i5yj2m8n15opapnwteqra.htm

You can add these options to your program:

```
options mfile mprint;
filename mprint 'debugmac';
```

And all the generated code will appear in the specified output file. This will *not* include `%PUT` statements though - in your example, your desired output includes a `%PUT` statement. The options above just redirect all the normal `MPRINT` lines to a file, so no open code or macro statements are include. You could probably find a way to append a header to the `MPRINT` file though, depending on your exact needs.

Having said all that, I wouldn't recommend your approach. Why would you want to flatten the program in this way? It's extremely unlikely to have any noticeable performance benefit, and will make it much harder to debug or modify the program in future.